# Slice item from (x,y) in javascript

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, logic, coordinates

i am new to javascript and would like to slice an item from a (x,y) like such. 
Say I have a group of coordinates that are different in length. How would I do such? Thanks?

`(142131,125124241t15135)// slice first item`

Answer (score 0):

You can use split rather than slice if you want first item from cordinates like this.

```
var str="(142131,125124241t15135)";
var firstValue=str.split(',')[0].replace("(","");
```